# Rails actiontext/trix display issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, trix, actiontext

I'm trying to incorporate a rich text editor into my app and am having no luck.  I was going to go with CKEditor, but ran across the fact that Rails 6 has actiontext/trix integrated pretty well.... or so I thought.

I followed the standard installation steps from https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_text_overview.html

So, unless I missed something, I now have the following code in these files:

**app/javascript/packs/actiontext.scss**

```
@import "trix/dist/trix";

.trix-content {
  .attachment-gallery {
    > action-text-attachment,
    > .attachment {
      flex: 1 0 33%;
      padding: 0 0.5em;
      max-width: 33%;
    }

    &.attachment-gallery--2,
    &.attachment-gallery--4 {
      > action-text-attachment,
      > .attachment {
        flex-basis: 50%;
        max-width: 50%;
      }
    }
  }

  action-text-attachment {
    .attachment {
      padding: 0 !important;
      max-width: 100% !important;
    }
  }
}
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")

import $ from 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
  $('body').tooltip({
    selector: '[data-toggle="tooltip"]',
    container: 'body',
  });

  $('body').popover({
    selector: '[data-toggle="popover"]',
    container: 'body',
    html: true,
    trigger: 'hover',
  });
});

require("trix")
require("@rails/actiontext")
```

**app/javascript/packs/application.scss**

```
@import "./actiontext.scss";
```

The model that I want the editor to show up for is:
**app/models/note.rb**

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  has_rich_text :comment
end
```

And the associated view/form is now below, with only the `comment` field being the rich enabled one:
**app/views/notes/edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @note, url: project_target_note_path(id: @note.id) do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :title %>
        <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :comment %>
        <%= f.rich_text_area :comment, cols: 20, rows: 40, class: "form-control" %>
    </div>
    <div>
        <%= f.submit "Update", class: "btn btn-success" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm at a loss here ... no buttons show up at all:

[image: form with no buttons!]

What have I missed?

**Update 1:**
I moved `actiontext.scss` from `.../packs/` and put it in `app/assets/stylesheets/` and changed some of the imports:

So, now `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` is simply:

```
//= require actiontext
```

I restarted webpacker and my rails server:

```
> bin/webpack-dev-server
> rails s
```

and now I am getting the buttons, but they do not have icons:
[image: update1]

Update 2:

Got the buttons to show with icons... finally.  Not sure if this is correct, since it's not documented, but I had to manually import `application.scss`.

**../layouts/application.html.erb**
I added:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application" %>
```

Comment: Welcome to the ActionText/ActiveStorage circus! Are you getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: Nothing at all!

Comment: I made a little progress by moving `actiontext.scss` into `app/stylesheets/` instead.  Now I get buttons, but they just a bunch of text, no icons...

Comment: can you check if you are also requiring "trix" inside of your actiontext.scss or application.scss? btw I think you'll need to set the height on your own, the rows/cols attributes don't seem to do anything

Comment: .form-control.trix-content {
    min-height:300px;
    max-height:80%;
    height:50%;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

Answer (score 9):

If anyone lands here with the same problem:
For me it helped to import both the trix style and the new actiontext style sheet in `application.scss` (not only the stylesheet like advised in the Rails guides).
And for me the order also mattered!

```
// application.scss
@import "trix/dist/trix";
@import "./actiontext.scss";
```

Comment: I was able to display Action Text in Rails 7 using Bootstrap having added the following to '/app/assets/stylesheets/application.bootstrap.scss'.


`@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons';
@import 'actiontext.css';
@import 'trix/dist/trix.css';`

Comment: I followed this recommendation but it's still not working properly when pushed up to heroku. When running locally, it works like a charm. In heroku it prints out words rather than showing symbols.

Answer (score 5):

For `rails 6`, you need to require `import 'trix/dist/trix.css';` inside `javascript/packs/application.js` (for the css styling)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Rails 7, I was having almost the same problems as yours where **actiontext trix display** was displaying only the buttons, but does not display the icons:
[image: Only showing buttons and NOT icons]

So after trying different approach to fix it, I realized that when using the **Rails 7 importmaps with Bootstrap** you do not need to create the `actiontext.scss` file and then import `'trix/dist/trix.css';` therein...
**All you have to do is:**
in your `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` import bootstrap and trix

```
@import "trix";
@import "bootstrap";
```

And in your`layouts/application.html.erb` you use `<%= javascript_importmap_tags %>` that's all, this will work fine! this fixed my issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think this is an ideal resolution, I provided 2 updates above that seems to resolve my issue.

1: keep `actiontext.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets` (where it was originally generated).

2: manually import `application.scss` in `..layouts/application.html.erb`